# Error TestEngine with ID 'junit-jupiter' failed to discover tests

Tags: java, spring, maven, junit5, junit-jupiter

I have the following error: 'org.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException: TestEngine with ID 'junit-jupiter' failed to discover tests' when trying to run a test from the package with the structure test/java/mytest.class.

[image]

I am using `<junit.jupiter.version>5.5.2</junit.jupiter.version>`

Comment: Show your pom file? Using an old version of junit jupiter and your Naming convention is wrong. Name the test class like `XYZTest.java` ... And also use `junit-jupiter-engine` as dependency (Which surefire version do you use?) and which version of IntelliJ Do you use?

Comment: Thanks for your response ! I use <maven-surefire.version>2.22.2</maven-surefire.version> , IntelliJ 2021.3.2. I have junit-vintage-engine, should I also add junit-jupiter-engine ?

Comment: Please show your test code....